# Were verse 35 and part of verse 34 in John 19 added by the Evangelist as an afterthought?

Tags: catholicism, gospel-of-john, crucifixion

We read in Jn 19:33-35 :

33. But when they came to Jesus and found that he was already dead, they did not break his legs. 34 Instead, one of the soldiers pierced Jesus’ side with a spear, bringing a sudden flow of blood and water. 35 The man who saw it has given testimony, and his testimony is true. He knows that he tells the truth, and he testifies so that you also may believe. 36 These things happened so that the scripture would be fulfilled: “Not one of his bones will be broken,” 37 and, as another scripture says, “They will look on the one they have pierced.”

A retired cardio-thoracic surgeon, Dr. Antony de Bono, feels that there is a simple reason for the outpouring of the “blood and water.” He writes:

Jesus had a haemothorax, which in the stillness of the dead body, had separated out as they do into two layers: the heavier red cells below and the light watery plasma above. The haemothorax was the result of the savage flagellation. The withdrawal of the spear would have been followed first by the red cells (blood), then by the lighter plasma (water). The body of Jesus had been hanging on the cross, dead, for some time. Obviously the fluid must have accumulated during life by a bleeding into the chest cavity, almost certainly due to the savage flagellation. It is well known that blood in these circumstances in a still dead body starts to separate out, to sediment, the heavier red cells sinking to the bottom leaving a much lighter, straw colored fluid, the plasma above. When a hole is made by the spear, the red cells, which John describes as blood, gushes out first, followed by the plasma, which John saw as water. (Courtesy: Aleteia-June 21 )

Now, verse 35 in the first appearance is a misfit in the flow of the narration , in that verse 36 immediately following verse 34 would have smoothly completed the narration. John appears to have added both the `flow of water' in verse 34 and his signature testimony in verse 35 as an afterthought,in order to pre-empt any theory  that Jesus did not actually die on the cross, which may have started circulating then.

My question therefore is: Were Verse 35 and part of verse 34 in  Jn 19 added by the Evangelist as an afterthought ? Do the teachings of Catholic Church say anything about such a prospect ?

Comment: This seems like speculation at best, possibly a better question for Bible Hermeneutics. John is writing later than the others and the other 3 are very clear that Christ died on the cross, so it seems unlikely that he would have to emphasize that even as an afterthought. Also, breaking the flow of narration is inconclusive -- parenthesis didn't exist/weren't used. It's not unusual for texts in that time period to include statements that would be in parentheses or footnotes in modern conventions.

Comment: I'm not sure what your quote from the cardiac surgeon has to do with the question.

Comment: A lot, in fact. In case John quoted only blood gushing out from the sphere wound, it  would still be challenged by skeptics who would say that blood also gushes out from the body of a living person. But the addition of `water' would state beyond an iota of doubt that Jesus had in deed been dead for some time when the sphere pierced his heart.  By the way, there are some people who believe that Jesus actually did not die on the cross, and was rejuvenated  by his disciples . They say he  traveled to  India and died later in Kahmir. It is possible that the theory went round as John was writing .